# Как из url-адреса получить нужные значения?

Tags: javascript

Получаю url. К примеру он такой:

```
.../index.html?FName=Sergey&LName=Ivanov&Email=s-ivanow@gmail.com
```

Как из него нужно получить значения `FName` (т.е. `Sergey`), `LName` (т.е. `Ivanov`) и `Email` (т.е. `s-ivanow@gmail.com`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const myUrl = 'https//example.com/index.html?FName=Sergey&LName=Ivanov&Email=s-ivanow@gmail.com';

const [url, params] = myUrl.split('?');

const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(params);

for (let [name, value] of searchParams) console.log(name, value);
```